# Sharing data between components with compostion API Vue.js3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So I have two components:

- Menu.vue
- Text.vue

Menu.vue:

```html
<template>
 <p @click="getSelected(rule.name)">{{ rule.name }}</p>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
function getSelected(ruleName) {
  console.log(ruleName);
  return ruleName;
};
</script>
```

I need to get `ruleName` value to my *Text.vue* component and store it in some variable. Something like this:

Text.vue

```html
<template>
 <p>{{ ruleName }}</p>
</template>
```

I only found solutions how to do it with `export default`, if I am getting this right this is not composition API and it does not work.

If i do this in Menu.vue:

```js
export default function getSelected(ruleName) {
  console.log(ruleName);
  return ruleName;
}
```

**Export** is underlined and it says that `Modifiers cannot appear here.`.

Can someone tell me how is this possible to do in composition API ?

Comment: It's unknown how these comps are related, which is important. "If i do this:" - in which file? The snippet lacks the context

Answer (score 0):

Define `props`

in `Menu.vue`

```
const props = defineProps({
  rule: Object
})
```

and in `Text.vue`

```
const props = defineProps({
  ruleName: String
})
```

Then you import the components in the place where you need them

```
import Menu from './Menu.vue'
import Text from './Text.vue'
```

and use

```
  <Text :ruleName="rule.name" />
  <Menu :rule="rule"/>
```

Here is [SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNUsFOwzAM/RUrQtomofVewgQXbgPEOOawrnNHoU2jNEWgKv+OnTbdhoTYLS9+fn5+SS/ujVl+dihSIdvclsZBi64zK6XL2jTWQQ8WC/BQ2KaGGVFnU2mNuhvvlwkDVjqWX/HLTWUGY1npvNGtA9tVCLc0QGc1pqDE+vuFrpTwSgMoLZPBEXkh4LA2VeaQEMADq5L1FGSYkrLWI8ncKsHHJUsqAUlgyzc7HoLjQB6JSnBFJpO6uBZxE87kdGoYGosXTZa7zrlGw11elfkHMQ7oNlhh7nA/n9gLJVY9xRwxeC+TofPcW8hhfKUq0wcSdC3NGl6MEvsn+CF2YxvTUu57LEqNz4zmPafDBlJ42r2TP6X9IjacmKa2otO5Kxsd/PPiCwjdWYXWzbfxlpizqz4iP9uSnL85eVQKOlr7HbQ0MY+gxHHwhzxL4u8cLtqThVPYOFvqw7Dr0Zj/AeH6FL4=)